# Errors when running npm install

Tags: angularjs, node.js, asp.net-core

This error keeps happening no matter where I run npm install. I've looked for answers and it appears none seem to match this particular case..

I am creating an ASP.NET Core application with Angular 2 using this as my guide. However no matter what guide I use I am getting this list of errors at the end of the npm-debug:

```
178 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
179 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
180 error node v4.4.7
181 error npm  v2.15.8
182 error code EPEERINVALID
183 error peerinvalid The package @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.7 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
183 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/forms@2.0.0-rc.7 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.7
183 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.7 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.7
183 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.7 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.7
183 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@3.0.0-rc.3 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.7
183 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-server@2.0.0 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0v
184 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

In this case I have a package.json file as follows:

```
{
"name": "aspnetcoreangular2webpackstarter",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && npm install && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"dotnet run\" \"npm run startWebpackDevServer\" ",
    "startWebpackDevServer": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "build": "SET NODE_ENV=development && webpack -d --color && dotnet run",
    "buildProduction": "SET NODE_ENV=production && webpack -d --color",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "Fabian Gosebrink",
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.21",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "jquery": "2.2.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.9.0",
    "webpack-stream": "^3.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "0.1.10",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "node-sass": "3.8.0",
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.3.2"
}
```

}

I seem to get this error no matter where I try and create project and then run "npm install"

I have placed asp.netcore in the list of tags as I am creating an angular 2 project in asp.netcore..

What do these errors mean and what do I do to remove them?

Comment: Delete node_modules\@angular\common folder and then run npm install again.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is install the missing dependencies:

`npm i @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.7`

Comment: Ran that and I got the same errors... whats missing here - it says "npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.7 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!"...

Comment: Check what version of `@angular/common ` you have installed. It needs to be `2.0.0-rc.7`

Comment: Ok.. how do I check the version. I tried to go to the console on chrome developer tools and typing in "angular.version.full" doesnt work.

Comment: `npm list` should give you the complete tree